# Batch/MS-Windows-CMD: Increment Number Not Incrementing in FOR Loop

Tags: windows

I have made a script:

```
set int=0
for /f %%i in ('type linksonpage.txt') DO set /a int=%int%+1
```

It just says 1 every time!
Note: I know about for /L (loop through numbers) and I cannot use it in this case.
I know that in CMD the %% is just % but that is not the issue

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it:

```
for /l %%g in (1,1,43) DO for /f %%i DO set /a int=%%g
```